# Debugging native app on ARM chromebook?

Tags: google-nativeclient

What's the easiest way to debug the ARM build of a Chrome NACL app (Samsung Chromebook) ?

Can we see printf output?  What about Chrome debug output?

Can we use gdb remotely?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this works and is the canonical repository of this kind of info.  (If it doesn't, the page should be fixed!)

http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/how-tos/debugging-documentation/debugging-with-debug-stub-recommended/debugging-nacl-apps-in-chrome-os

Yes, you can use gdb remotely.

To see printf output, try chrome:://system and expanding the ui_log.